# Chrome extension permissions got errors while loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome extension with javascript files stored local has to be executed. I got permission errors.

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:5000". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

My permissions in Manifest

```
"permissions" : ["activeTab"],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' ; object-src 'self'"
```

Comment: It's telling you what to do in the error message.

Comment: used unsafe-inline got error while loading the extension
Ignored insecure CSP value "'unsafe-inline'" in directive 'script-src'.

Comment: Can you not use the inline code and instead do it safe using a separate js file?